# type void is not assignable to array

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a method that removes all the zeros from a string (a string that contains numbers) for each element of an array;

I get this error 'type void is not assignable to programs[]

```
 public removeLeadingZeros(programs: Program[]) {
    let programCopy: Program[];
    programCopy= programs.forEach(p => {
      p.number.replace(/^0+/, '');
    });

    return programCopy;
  }
```

Comment: Specify the return type of your function. In addition, why are you returning `dealPrograms` ? I don't see it declared anywhere in your function.

Comment: Just use `return programs.filter(p => return p.number.replace(/^0+/, ''))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to the other answer, instead of using `.forEach()` which doesn't return anything, you can use the `.map()` which returns an array of what you have changed.

```
let programCopy: Program[];
programCopy = programs.map(p => {
  p.number.replace(/^0+/, '');
  return p;
});
```

EDIT: Here is the shorter version of this code

```
let programCopy: Program[] = programs.map(p => p.number.replace(/^0+/, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because **forEach** does not have any return type.

if you want to store the objects with the replaced numbers in programCopy just copy the programs parameter and change them:

```
programCopy = programs;
programCopy.forEach(p => {
  p.number.replace(/^0+/, '');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead of forEach loop:

```
programCopy = programs.filter(p => p !== 0);
```

You can use filter method. It returns an array of the filtered items.
Now, the programCopy variable contains the number without zeros.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this approach.

```js
public removeLeadingZeros(programs: Program[]) {
    let programCopy: Program[];
    programs.forEach(p => {
      programCopy.push(p.number.replace(/^0+/, ''))

    });

    return programCopy;
  }
```